# What is the purpose of back() in c++?

Tags: c++, string, hashmap, hashtable

Here is the code:

```
class Solution {
public:
    int romanToInt(string s) {
        unordered_map<char, int> list = {
            {'I', 1},
            {'V', 5},
            {'X', 10},
            {'L', 50},
            {'C', 100},
            {'D', 500},
            {'M', 1000}
        };
        int total = list[s.back()];
        for(int i = s.length() - 2; i>=0; --i){
            if(list[s[i]] < list[s[i+1]]){
                total -= list[s[i]];
            }
            else{
                total += list[s[i]];
            }
        }
        return total;
    }
};
```

I can't understand what is the purpose of this line:

```
int total = list[s.back()];
```

can anyone tell me what is the purpose of

> "back()"

in the above code?

Comment: Have you read the reference?  https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/back

Comment: What do you mean, "in a hash table"? It's being called on `s`. That isn't a hash table. It's a string. Calling it gives you the *key* that will be used for `operator[]`. That's what's being used on the hash table.

Comment: `s.back()` returns the last letter of the string. No idea what's the purpose. Looks like random school exercise.

Comment: Note that `s.length()` returns an *unsigned* value, so `s.length() - 2` will wrap around to a very large number, before being assigned to `int i`, if `s` has less than 2 characters in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I have understood the string s contains a number using Roman numerals as for example `"IV"` that represents 4. So the expression s.back() yields the last symbol in the string that is `'V'`.

That is the string is traversed from right to left.

In other words, for sequential containers with rare exceptions the member function `front` yields the first element of the container and the function `back` yields the last element of the container.